# R-code for triple nested sums running in different indices

Tags: statistics

Dear friends please can you help me in solving this problem? IN R program?
I have this nested sums ∑∑∑AkBiCj with indices k,i,j all running from 1 to N, however this sums are performed only for  k different to i and different to j that is, all indices must be different to each other, for example k=1,i=2,j=3 only these situations. A,B and C are vector of values. What I need is a code where I can express this as product of double sum and a single sum like ∑∑AkBi*∑Cj this will help speed up my computations. the problem is that the sum ∑Cj will include include all elements, which will be wrong in general

Answer (score 1):

You can do $(\sum A_k)(\sum B_i)(\sum Cj)$ and subtract off the elements you do not want.  This is $(\sum A_kB_k)( \sum C_j)+(\sum A_kC_k)( \sum B_j)+(\sum C_kB_k)( \sum A_j)$ but now you have added all the terms with all the three indices matching once and subtracted them three times, so add them in twice as $ 2\sum A_kB_kC_k$  See the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: I am very glad for your help. Thank you very much it helped alot